# Text Based Tutorials for Unity3d

Tags: unity

I hope this is the right place to ask this. I'm very new to Unity but not to programming. I also have some basic game programming experience.

I'm searching for text based versions of the videos from `unity3d.com/learn/tutorials`. These tutorials are very good, but I end up forwarding videos a lot to get key screenshots and code snippets.

Is there any text / pdf / html / .doc / .rtf (i'm very open) version or similar resource to learn unity? Again, those tutorials are amazing and I'd hope to find something of similar quality, but I know that if I have to skim through tens of hours of video I'll end up frustrated. I get that the long hard way is probably the most robust one for deeper understanding, but I was hoping to hack a quick project.

EDIT :

If this can make it a relevant question, then I am currently looking at the "[Roll a Ball Tutorial](https://unity3d.com/learn/tutorials/projects/roll-ball-tutorial)". Really, any other text tutorial would be very welcome

Comment: Usually I vote to close questions asking for tutorials in general, but in this case you're looking for a pretty specific document so I think this question is on-topic. Also, I have to agree I hate trying to pick this stuff up from videos - I much prefer text I can search for keywords to jump straight to the step I need! I hope the text versions you want exist — the videos I've watched from this series are quite good, but way too rambling to use for quick reference.

Comment: Gotta love how the SE community is still so purist that it willingly shoots down good questions with good answers all the time.

Answer (score 2):

You can look into [noobtuts.com](http://noobtuts.com/unity). I've learn a lot of basics for Unity3D from here.

More text tutorial can be found on [catlikecoding.com](http://catlikecoding.com/unity/tutorials/).
And another on [raywenderlich.com](http://www.raywenderlich.com/61532/unity-2d-tutorial-getting-started) (it's for Unity 4.3 but it's not very different now)

Comment: Thanks, this is very relevant. Unfortunately, many of those tutorials are behind a 30$ paywall. Hopefully I'll be able to get enough traction to be know what I don't know from the free content. If nothing else comes up I'll mark you as accepted but I was hoping for something better.

Answer (score 0):

I highly recommend [Catlike Coding tutorials](http://catlikecoding.com/unity/tutorials/). They are a great resource for learning Unity and game related C# coding.

Answer (score 0):

There are plenty of free options out there.

- [Tutsplus](http://code.tutsplus.com/categories/unity-3d) - This might be your best bet.  It has Numerous tutorials along the lines of "How to make a game like X" that start right at creating the project.

Some others:

- [Ray Wenderlich's Unity Tutorial](http://www.raywenderlich.com/category/unity) - Covers 2d/3d, particles, multiplayer, basic Unity project architecture.
- [Unity 5 From Zero to Proficiency](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B019L2YF4Y) - Completely free book
- [AlexStv's Voxel Tutorial](http://alexstv.com/index.php/category/voxel-tutorial) - How to create a full voxel based engine in Unity (more advanced)